# What would cause arc4random_uniform to re-generate the same sequences?

Tags: ios, random, shuffle, arc4random

I'm shuffling an array using arc4random_uniform() as following:

```
int count = [arr count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   int n = arc4random_uniform(count - i) + i;
   [arr exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

The array contains 32 playing cards, and many users have reported that they're seeing the same card sequences, repeatedly. The procedure for creating the array is as following:

1. Add all the cards in a particular order to the array;
2. shuffle the array using the above loop.

I understand from the docs that arc4random_uniform doesn't require seeding. So my questions are:

1. What would cause the sequence generated by arc4random_uniform to repeat?
2. Is there anything I can do to minimize the probability that it would repeat other than saving the last sequence generated? Is shuffling it many times based on a random number a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into an app I am working on.

routine is called x times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    [self trySort];
}
```

routine loads an array, sorts it, then prints it:

```
- (void)trySort {
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", nil];
    //code pasted from question
    int count = [arr count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int n = arc4random_uniform(count - i) + i;
        [arr exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
    //
    NSLog(@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@", [arr objectAtIndex:0], [arr objectAtIndex:1], [arr objectAtIndex:2], [arr objectAtIndex:3], [arr objectAtIndex:4], [arr objectAtIndex:5], [arr objectAtIndex:6], [arr objectAtIndex:7], [arr objectAtIndex:8], [arr objectAtIndex:9], [arr objectAtIndex:10], [arr objectAtIndex:11]);
}
```

Results are reasonably sorted:

```
2013-04-07 16:24:50.923 xxx[2122:c07] BIAKHFDEGCLJ
2013-04-07 16:24:50.927 xxx[2122:c07] DGICJHLBAKFE
2013-04-07 16:24:50.928 xxx[2122:c07] HIGEFADJLCKB
2013-04-07 16:24:50.928 xxx[2122:c07] IHFDBJEALCKG
2013-04-07 16:24:50.928 xxx[2122:c07] GBEHIFCKAJDL
```

Is it possible that between the time your array is loaded and the time it is sorted, something happens to prevent the sort?

Comment: Thank you Rick. I agree with you, I also couldn't reproduce the problem, and that's why I'm asking about what would cause the problem to occur. They say that the cards are actually always shuffled, but the results of the shuffles themselves occur multiple times. For example if the result of a shuffle is the sequence DEFGRSKL, they'd see it more than once in a short period of time.